# EF migration raw sql read full record

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have student entity

```
public class Student
{
 public string FName {get; set;}
 public string LName {get; set;}
 public string DOB{get; set;}
}
```

In my database `Student` table, i have one record exist

```
I want to read this whole record using raw SQL inside my entity migration.
```

So far i could get only single column as below

```
var student= _context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT FName FROM Student").FirstOrDefault();
```

How i can read full record?

Comment: my question would be why RAW SQL if you don't need to?

Answer (score 1):

You're only selecting one column in your query there (`FName`), hence you only get one column in your result. You want to use `SELECT *`, which selects all columns in the table.

```
var student = _context.Database.SqlQuery<Student>("SELECT * FROM Student").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: change the type from string to Student #tag

Answer (score -1):

instead on SqlQuery ,use SqlQuery so it will return all column

Example

```
var student= _context.Database.SqlQuery<Student>("SELECT * FROM Student").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This still only gets a `Student` with `FName` populated, it doesn't "read the whole record" as described by the asker.

Comment: sry use like var student= _context.Database.SqlQuery<Student>("SELECT * FROM Student").FirstOrDefault();